# Match an email address if it contains a dot

Tags: c#, regex

I want to match any email address, that contains at least one `.` (dot) before the `@` sign. The emails have already been validated, so the regex just needs to search for the `.`.

I have tried

```
Regex emailMatcher = new Regex(@"^[a-zA-Z\.']{1,}\.[a-zA-Z\.']{1,}@example\.com$");
```

But I know that emails can contain more characters than just `a-zA-Z\.'` so this won't cover all cases.

Any ideas on how to do it?

Thanks

**EDIT:**
I'm not trying to validate emails, I already have the emails validated, I just need to select emails, that contain `.` before `@` sign

Examples that would pass:

```
first.last@example.com
first.middle.last@example.com
```

Examples that should pass, but wouldn't pass using my current regex

```
first.last(comment)@example.com
```

Comment: Do yourself a favor and use the search or a web search engine. Type in "email regex" and use another way of validation.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't think you read the question. I'm not trying to validate emails. I already have a set of emails that are valid, I just need to select ones, that contain dot before `@` sign. And yes, I have used google before asking.

Comment: I tried your regex in a tester and it looks like it is doing what you want. When does it fail ?

Comment: So then give some example input and output. What email addresses do you want to match, why doesn't this regex help there and what have you tried to make it match?

Comment: ^[a-zA-Z0-9()\.']{1,}\.[a-zA-Z0-90()\.']{1,}@example\.com$ this will match the example you gave

Comment: Just FYI: this regex will only match emails with a dot before the `@` sign: `^(?=[^@]+\.@)[a-zA-Z\.']{1,}\.[a-zA-Z\.']{1,}@example\.com$`. See https://regex101.com/r/cN7lH2/1.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could do this without a regex

```
Func<string, bool> dotBeforeAt = delegate(string email) 
{ 
    var dotIndex = email.IndexOf(".");
    return dotIndex > -1 && (dotIndex < email.IndexOf("@"));
};
...
emails.Where(dotBeforeAt).ToList();
```

[Try it out](http://ideone.com/pRO8RO)

Comment: Something like `.Where(x => {int i = x.IndexOf("."); return i > 0 &&i < x.IndexOf("@");})` would be better I guess ....

Comment: @Markus yep, although I'd argue having a named delegate is better from a readability perspective. `Where(dotBeforeAt)` just looks much better :)

Comment: There are multiple good, but this one seems to be one that I'll use. Thanks again!

Comment: @Bongo this isn't an email validator, it's a filter. The OP just wants all email addresses that contain a `.` before the `@` symbol - this code does that. The OP has already pre-validated the emails beforehand.

Comment: @James okay true. haven't said anything :)

Answer (score 3):

> I just need to select ones, that contain dot before @ sign

Then there is no point to build a regex that matches valid e-mail addresses. All you need is a regex that sees that there is a dot in front of the `@` sign:

```
(?<=[.][^@]*)@
```

`(?<=[.][^@]*)` is a positive lookbehind construct. It ensures that the `@` sign following it is matched only when there is a dot `[.]` followed by zero or more non-`@` characters in front of it.

Comment: I'd use `[.](?=[^@]*@)` myself... :p (in seriousness, you don't even need lookaround, just `[.].*@` )

Answer (score 2):

You can use lookahead.. for this purpose..

```
(?=\.).+@
```

Explanation:

- Look forward for a dot, followed by any characters followed by `@`

**Edit:** To match the email with the above criteria.. you can use

```
.+(?=\..+@).+
```

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/qO5vS5/1)

Comment: Thanks! I modified it to be `.+(?=\.).+` since there can be chars before the `.`

Comment: @user1680977 `.+(?=\.).+` wont check for `dot before @ sign` use the updated answer :)

Answer (score 2):

LinQ could be used to both avoid a regex and to avoid calling `IndexOf()` twice  on ".":

```
var dottyEmails = (from email in emails 
                   let dotIndex = email.IndexOf(".")
                   let atIndex = email.IndexOf("@")
                   where dotIndex >= 0 && dotIndex < atIndex
                   select email).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

[James' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30076595/11963) will probably give you the best performance. However, the `IndexOf` approach will not handle a quoted-string (ie. `"abc@.xtest.yz"@example.com`, which is a valid address according to [RCF 5322](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322#section-3.4)). To support that case, and if performance is not an issue, you could also use the following, which is a little bit more readable and verbose on what the intention of the LINQ query is:

```
emails.Select(m => new MailAddress(m)).Where(m => m.User.Contains('.')).ToList();
```

The overhead of building the `MailAddress` objects is pretty obvious, but this makes it really clear that you want those addresses that have a dot in the local part of the address.